# Detecting deadlocks in thread safe linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, thread-safety, deadlock

I recently got a homework to implement a thread safe singly linked list which locks elements in hand over hand method which means that there is a single lock for every element in the list.I implemented  all the functions and tested them without having to deal with problematic thread situations and they all worked but I wanted to test if there could be a situation of a deadlock or a starvation but I do not know how to do it and can I know from looking at my code if I could have deadlock or starvation ? I am also not sure if there there needs to be this much locking and unlocking in the code.
Note that in each function I lock an element and it's successor, is that enough ? Any help or suggestion regarding my code if it its prone to deadlocks and starvation or any other problems ? I will post my  code below. Thanks in advance.

concurrent_list.h :

```
typedef struct node node;
typedef struct list list;

list* create_list();
void delete_list(list* list);
void print_list(list* list);
void insert_value(list* list, int value);
void remove_value(list* list, int value);
void count_list(list* list, int (*predicate)(int));
```

concurrent_list.c :

```
 #include <pthread.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <limits.h>
 #include "concurrent_list.h"

struct node {
  int value;
  node* next;
  pthread_mutex_t lock; // hand over hand implies a lock for every node
};

struct list {
  node* head;
};

// print the value of a node
void print_node(node* node)
{
  if(node)
  {
    printf("%d ", node->value);
  }

}

// create  a new empty list
list* create_list()
{
    list* l =(list*)malloc(sizeof(list));

    if(l == NULL) return NULL;

    l->head = NULL;

    return l;
}

// delete the entire list
void delete_list(list* list)
{
  if(list == NULL) return; // if list pointer is NULL then do nothing

  node* current = list->head;

  if(current == NULL) return; // if list head is NULL then do nothing

  pthread_mutex_lock(&(current->lock)); // lock list head

  node* temp = current->next;
  node* dummy;

  if(temp == NULL) // delete the only element in the list
  {
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock));
     pthread_mutex_destroy(&(current->lock));
     free(current);
     return;
  }

  pthread_mutex_lock(&(temp->lock)); //lock successor of the head

  while (1)
  {
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock)); // unlock current node
     dummy = current;
     current = temp; // current becomes it's successor
     pthread_mutex_destroy(&(dummy->lock));
     free(dummy); // free dummy because it is a pointer to current
     temp = temp->next; // current becomes it's successor
     if(temp == NULL) break; // exit loop if we are at the end of the 
     list
     pthread_mutex_lock(&(temp->lock)); // lock current's successor
  }

     pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock));
     pthread_mutex_destroy(&(current->lock));
     free(current); // free the last element in the list
     list->head = NULL;
     free(list); // free the list
  }

  // insert function for a new value if a value already exists then do 
  nothing
  void insert_value(list* list, int value)
  {
     if(list == NULL) return; // if list pointer is NULL then do nothing

     node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node)); // create new node

     if(new_node == NULL) return; // check if allocation fails

     new_node->value = value;

     new_node->next = NULL;

     pthread_mutex_init(&(new_node->lock),NULL);  // initialize fast mutex lock for the new node

     pthread_mutex_lock(&(new_node->lock)); // lock the new node

     if(list->head == NULL) // new node is the first element in the list
     {
        new_node->next = NULL;
        list->head = new_node;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(new_node->lock));
        return;
     }

      pthread_mutex_lock(&(list->head->lock)); // lock the head of the list

      node* temp;

      if(list->head->value >= new_node->value) // new node comes before the list head
     {
       new_node->next = list->head;
       temp = list->head;
       list->head = new_node;
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&(list->head->lock));
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&(temp->lock));
       return;
     }

    else
    {
      // Locate the node before the point of insertion //

     node* dummy;
     node* current = list->head;
     temp = current->next;

     if(temp == NULL) // new node comes after the list head
     {
         new_node->next = current->next;
         current->next = new_node;
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&(new_node->lock));
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock));
         return;
     }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(temp->lock)); // lock the successor of the head

  // perform hand over hand traversal of the list
  // and check if temp reaches the end of the list (NULL)

   while (temp->value < new_node->value)
   {
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock));
     current = temp;
     temp = temp->next;
     if(temp == NULL) break;
     pthread_mutex_lock(&(temp->lock));
   }

   if(temp == NULL) // new node will be the last element in this case
   {
       current->next = new_node;
       new_node->next = NULL;
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock));
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&(new_node->lock));
       return;
   }

   else // new node should be inserted inside the list
   {
       dummy = temp;
       new_node->next = current->next;
       current->next = new_node;
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&(dummy->lock));
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock));
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&(new_node->lock));
       return;
   }
 }
}

 //delete the first appearance of a value in the list if it exists in the list
    void remove_value(list* list, int value)
    {
      if(list == NULL) return; // if list pointer is NULL then do nothing

      node* temp;
      node* current = list->head;

      if(current == NULL) return; // if list head is NULL then just go to a new line

     pthread_mutex_lock(&(current->lock)); // lock the head of the list

     if(current->value == value) // delete the head of list if it's value is equal to given value
    {
        temp = current;
        list->head = current->next;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(temp->lock));
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&(temp->lock));
       free(temp);
       return;
   }

    else
   {
       temp = current->next;

       if(temp == NULL)
       {
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock));
           return;
       }

       pthread_mutex_lock(&(temp->lock)); // lock the successor of the head

        // perform hand over hand traversal of the list
       //  and check if temp reaches the end of the list (NULL)

    while (temp->value != value) // find the first appearance of a node 
    that has a value the same as the one given
        {
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock));
          current = temp;
          temp = temp->next;
          if(temp == NULL) break;
          pthread_mutex_lock(&(temp->lock));
        }

         if(temp == NULL) // value not found
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock));
            return;
        }

        else // delete the suitable node
        {
            current->next = temp->next;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock));
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&(temp->lock));
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&(temp->lock));
            free(temp);
           return;
        }
    }
}

 //print the entire list
 void print_list(list* list)
 {
  if(list == NULL) // if list pointer is NULL then just go to a new line
  {
      printf("\n");
      return;
  }

      node* current = list->head;

      if(current == NULL) // if list head is NULL then just go to a new line
      {
         printf("\n");
         return;
      }

      pthread_mutex_lock(&(current->lock)); // lock the head of the list

      print_node(current); // print the head of the list

      node* temp = current->next;

      if(temp == NULL) // a list with 1 element
      {
         printf("\n");
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock));
         return;
      }

     pthread_mutex_lock(&(temp->lock)); // lock the list head's successor

    while (1)
    {
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock)); // unlock current node
       current = temp; // current becomes it's successor
       print_node(current); // print current node
       temp = temp->next; // // temp becomes it's successor
       if(temp == NULL) break; // exit loop if we reach the end of the list
      pthread_mutex_lock(&(temp->lock)); // lock temp
   }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock)); // unlock the last list 
    element
   printf("\n");
}

 // print how many nodes in the list satisfy a given predicate function
 void count_list(list* list, int (*predicate)(int))
 {

   int count = 0;

   if(list == NULL) // if list pointer is NULL then print that count = 
   0 and finish
   {
      printf("%d items were counted\n", count);
      return;
   }

   node* current = list->head;

   if(current == NULL) // if list head is NULL then print that count = 
   0 and finish
   {
       printf("%d items were counted\n", count);
       return;
   }

   pthread_mutex_lock(&(current->lock)); // lock the list head

   if(predicate(current->value)) count++; // check the predicate for 
   the list head

   node* temp = current->next;

   if(temp == NULL) // list has only 1 element
   {
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock));
      printf("%d items were counted\n", count);
      return;
   }

   pthread_mutex_lock(&(temp->lock)); // lock the list head's successor

   while (1)
  {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock)); // unlock current node
    current = temp; // current becomes it's successor
    if(predicate(current->value)) count++; // check predicate for current node
    temp = temp->next; // // temp becomes it's successor
    if(temp == NULL) break; // exit loop if we reach the end of the list
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(temp->lock)); // lock temp
   }

   pthread_mutex_unlock(&(current->lock)); // unlock the last list element

   printf("%d items were counted\n", count); // print count
}
```

Comment: Since the code is asserted to work (modulo possible locking issues), the question would probably be better suited for [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  As posed, it's a bit too broad for SO.

Comment: You need to lock the head whenever you access it. E.g. in `insert_value` right after `if(list->head == NULL)`, the condition may no longer hold true if another thread adds a node right then. --- You may be able to simplify your logic by adding a permanent dummy head node.

Comment: John Bollinger thanks I posted my code there

Answer (score 0):

There is always the risk that the user-code of that list will be deadlocked (deadlock itself or mutually with other user-code). You can not protect against that.

Before thinking about whether there are possible deadlocks in the list-code itself, the code has to be corrected:

The list itself is not locked. Replacing the `head` cannot safely be done.

In `delete_list`:

- in the case of a single-entry list (temp == NULL): you unlock and then free: that is a race that invalidates the lock. Also, it is unnecessary to unlock anyway because that memory will be freed.
- similarily for the case where the list contains more elements, but you also find out the successor after unlocking (note that some other thread might see the unlock and change the successor-pointer, then the first thread continues to run with the wrong successor)

I did not continue, but guess that there are similar issues in the rest of the code. Those issues should be fixed before finding deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you over-complicated the problem and, as a result, there are several situations where you will still get in the concurrently updated list.

For example, in your `insert_value` you have the following lines bevore you lock the head of the list:

```
 node* current = list->head;
 temp = current->next;
```

this could cause issues if the other thread tries to delete the head at the same time.
There are probably others.

In many cases you lock `new` value where it is not needed because the value is created by a thread and is not shared yet.

Usually one uses a single mutex for the whole list if you do operations on the list. locking of the elements might be needed if you allow concurrent modifications of the element.

I guess in your case locking just the head element will be sufficient for most of the operations.

Comment: Yes locking the list itself is how it is usually done, but I guess it was the boss/teacher's requirement to use the "hand over hand" method. Yes there are many more issues: I wrote a few in my answer but did not continue reading either. Be careful when you write a version that does not lock a new node: From your point it looks like another thread has no access yet, but from the compiler's view it looks like it is free to reorder statements. If you dont use a lock then you have to use a fence.